# Online update spanner schema is extremely slow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

Online updating spanner schema takes minutes even for very very small tables (10s of rows).

i.e. - adding/dropping/altering columns, adding tables, etc.
This can be quite frustrating for development processes and new version deployments.

Any plans for improvement?

Few more questions:

1. Anyone knows a 3rd party schema comparison tool for spanner? couldn't find any.
2. What about data backups? in order to save historical snapshots.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Schema Updates:
Since Cloud Spanner is a distributed database, it makes sure to update all moving parts of the system which takes the latency as described.

As a suggestion, you could batch the schema updates. This ensures the lower latencies (nearly equivalent to executing a single schema update) and can be executed using API / gcloud command-line tools.

Schema Comparison Tool:
You could use the [getDatabaseDdl](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/0.17.0/apidocs/index.html?com/google/cloud/spanner/DatabaseAdminClient.html) API to maintain history of your schema changes and use your tool of choice to diff them.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, about the batch schema updates - I'll check, if it's nearly equivalent to executing a single schema update, then it's good enough.
About getDatabaseDdl - yes I know. But I was hoping to some better tool to compare between databases, which allows to easily update the changes (such as RedGate SQL compare, etc).
Btw - backups are major concern for us.

Comment: Just confirmed that batch schema updates is indeed faster! thanks. I'll set your reply as an answer